# Writing multi line string to yaml file using go

Tags: go, yaml

I need to write multiline string as a value to a yaml file in go. When I marshal the data, I am getting \n in my data like this.

```
ApiVersion: v1
name: td-agent-bit-config
namespace: logging
labels:
  k8s-app: td-agent-bit-logging
data: "\n\tapiVersion: v1\n\tkind: ConfigMap\n\tmetadata:\n\tname: td-agent-bit-config\n\tnamespace:
  se\n\tlabels:\n\t  k8s-app: td-agent-bit-logging\n\tdata:"
```

If I write it as a string then I am getting indentation problem.

````
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
      name: td-agent-bit-config
      namespace: se
      labels:
        k8s-app: td-agent-bit-logging
    data:
      actinium.conf: |
[INPUT]
    Name        tail
    Buffer_Max_Size 3M
    Buffer_Chunk_Size 3M
    Mem_Buf_Limit 100MB
    Tag actinium.*```
````

My yaml file should look like

```
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: td-agent-bit-config
  namespace: se
  labels:
    k8s-app: td-agent-bit-logging
data:
  fluent-bit.conf: |
    [SERVICE]
        Flush         1
        Log_Level     info
        Daemon        off
    @INCLUDE input-kubernetes.conf
    @INCLUDE filter-kubernetes.conf
    @INCLUDE output-kafka.conf

  input-kubernetes.conf: |
    [INPUT]
        Name        tail
        Buffer_Max_Size 3M
        Buffer_Chunk_Size 3M
        Mem_Buf_Limit 100MB
        Tag <serviceName>.*
        Path        /myntra/<serviceName>/logs/*/*
        DB /var/log/<serviceName>.db
        Refresh_Interval 10s
        Rotate_Wait 10s
```

Can anyone please help in resolving this issue?

Comment: Can you add the src code ur using, so it would be easier to build on top of it

Comment: could you please clarify: how are your three examples related? can you come up with a [mre] that shows current input and output, vs. expected output, alongside with the code you use?

Answer (score 0):

i don't konw how you marshal/Unmarshal yaml

but there is no problem if you uses https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml (go get gopkg.in/yaml.v2)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

var data = `
a: Easy!
b:
  c: 2
  d: [3, 4]
e:  |
    [SERVICE]
        Flush         1
        Log_Level     info
        Daemon        off
    @INCLUDE input-kubernetes.conf
    @INCLUDE filter-kubernetes.conf
    @INCLUDE output-kafka.conf
`

// Note: struct fields must be public in order for unmarshal to
// correctly populate the data.
type T struct {
    A string
    B struct {
        RenamedC int   `yaml:"c"`
        D        []int `yaml:",flow"`
    }
    E string
}

func main() {
    t := T{}

    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &t)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("--- t:\n%v\n\n", t)

    d, err := yaml.Marshal(&t)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("--- t dump:\n%s\n\n", string(d))
}
```

```
--- t:
{Easy! {2 [3 4]} [SERVICE]
    Flush         1
    Log_Level     info
    Daemon        off
@INCLUDE input-kubernetes.conf
@INCLUDE filter-kubernetes.conf
@INCLUDE output-kafka.conf
}

--- t dump:
a: Easy!
b:
  c: 2
  d: [3, 4]
e: |
  [SERVICE]
      Flush         1
      Log_Level     info
      Daemon        off
  @INCLUDE input-kubernetes.conf
  @INCLUDE filter-kubernetes.conf
  @INCLUDE output-kafka.conf
```